# interact port usb on java

Tags: java, usb

I'm researching about to interact with port usb on java, I have found two libraries JSR-80 and jusb. Could you tell me wich is better? or if to exist any other?

Note: I´m working under linux

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/)

> libusb is a C library that gives applications easy access to USB
>   devices on many different operating systems. libusb is an open source
>   project

See the [Libusb java binding on github](https://github.com/trygvis/javax-usb-libusb1)

alternativly there is [usb4java](http://kayahr.github.com/usb4java/) from which The low-level part is based on the native libusb 0.1

Answer (score 1):

Both are good for Linux but have some limitations on Windows
[rxtx](http://ww6.rxtx.org/) is another very good library for this.Anyway I suggest you [this wonderful article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/06/java-and-usb.html) in which you can see detail on both (JSR-80 & JUSB) :)